# Generating audio file manually

Tags: javascript, audio, binary, base64

I'm trying to understand how generate audio based on a string. Think of how you can open a non-audio file in something like Audacity (it opens as binary I guess) and play it as noise.

I have a simple working player in tone.js below that plugs in a base64 string of an audio file to the player. How do I replace that base64 audio file with an ordinary string (text), say "Hello world", that gets converted into an audio file as a string, either as bas64 as below as perhaps using binary conversion?

```
<script>

//load a base64 mp3
const player = new Tone.Player("data:audio/mp3;base64, //uQxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWGluZwAAAA8AAAAOAAAXnwAXFxcXFxcXKioqKioqKj09PT09PT1QUFBQUFBQY2NjY2NjY3Z2dnZ2dnaJiYmJiYmJiZycnJycnJyvr6+vr6+vwsLCwsLCwtXV1dXV1dXo6Ojo6Ojo+/v7+/v7+/////////8AAABNTEFNRTMuOTZyBL4AAAAAAAAAADSAJAXxQQAB4AAAF59rEpVtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//ugxAAADZRLWHTxgCzvtGz/P+jYACKbvBVljPQGwAaAEAGATAyGe79jZ37+/d3d3d3REQAAAAAQWHh4eHgAA7///gB4eHh4YAAAAAB4eHj////XgAABh4eHh4AAAAABh4e////wAPwAA8PDw8MAAAAEB4eHv///3YAAABh4eHh4AYBABAhJlKHTL/v7aGwQAAbPpzFGJZCQZhvovyYK4AkmQohdhgXIC2cUlK6mLDm3hgHgBOYAgAPmALAC0aMhzIOjMoUOQDAGohABL+jk85ZOySA1MVkWXTW0Y9M4lfo2jU6EUnSTG3/mPmkGZf5sRiMgJGP6q8jO5Vul/HnmL0TSZLhApjlDumFaMcY+ZBDAnjaa7MO475vzHdGAMCII8w0BAzECDlMA8BAwAAPZiI0USuSr/7r/MCgDELgEGBWCwYP4UhgSAnmCUCaYNQS/csu1s6X////zARAyMCsBwwFQFAIAmYDQCKABIWOCIA3fP/9f///////oCizRZZNEAAAmAEACyJE4u84MV///////////////VaZXK+ztK3MhYi1l4mdQr5T////////////////////UiMOuzfUAAKW3772IkGH2I/5iMoWYYP+CGBYCZMB6ANzAHgAsKgCwGAJp+6hJb21ruGetpn+XsLklSJ7bBJsgdRN7wPrvM2WwSSRBllkj4NWA//uQxCYAEPTZK73zACGimmX17IxczdKLZA/bNsvqzlF/fKOvPmn9O33wy5BU24LhhlYSGEmKSlTFxEPCqQSlAEXFg9QK+436EkcUKnlL2/9YAAdu33/1aINYJyw1dQgQgjkwYQIjgVM0AMFT6g6gazLgsPtQ55nArMyqFcEIqPU3QUC7glDJ7o9XUFRZN1xtwpB8xIUOQWTNKrRgSGRCFpFAkE3RodCMCJSx6iTlZ86/QbtoS53Z0fqVAAAkZmh///W0TRNbQMQQMg3bTOGQ3YI78OOXGwWH0dcs8NOqKKQhs1ZsHIQplNdDIuykHK3Y1IFjxLs7QMnks3QaYLitDHPq3q5GzCQtEPL13fNS901/fCN8vFe+iN97zto55qipVLTpdLGMF0e3L+66oAAqW76/WtEGL7IWY3wdZ56G0yYISAVdzu02MusttTJ5e1WGtd1pmwt6grBRggEH18NYEkSGVAKlcAQGeCFNmERglchkBMwqqIdlkciI0M6PuBgOAVZZg4GAISaoUMg8CWOYVEI2ZQkyOb/5u2xT0gAApdd///uQxHOADlEhMe9lAOG9m6W17IwktokQaCR3RkBggHUIgJkEBUrmmwNOXBBZb6nSXa/7mFsgbK+hhCxBIgd2NtmRi2ciRzINmJIjzXB+A8YetOs3S9JEuTbM2VuvfNZmfFXvQsBgmWAY8AtaiKi4suiMQMh5gkSz/7bdZIAF223/7WtEHxfCGjggAcNGht4Ei8sh+nBLbHrO8/Kb7Z+/ClSWV6OMPMMiSv0ciHJcrH1uW5iNtPjtdInwYgQvBD2fL98FlRu27Op/h37u8/afaSiLbFJN4wbNXt3DSvn3jF/94simIKaimZccmxcY1VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVUAFx13b61pEGIUs2YOgO5pwDAqZNZdqUzV6esn61/PpnagN8hI4aMo4kSUGYKIFjxncUDujhyRdBFECwjhNgwRDMhok1csbY84+cpPx+mEL3/Km5mx2Mdt1xzZiyMU9EqoNk0WCYsIyFHSrcWAZAyu1H7P//uQxMiADYjbLa9pAOGbnaW13JgdsAAJGQFeN/9WkTZCrjNcKDBYAS+S6Xea7Fp25GbR/mVglpd4PIGfdZHpnkoLiF/aKgz8xF1HupjcBTW09ND3yfjIVbzuHtsn7arySxR59zGPJxdSkC5EsWFzzRohU8k9JYKKPMRE6iyWPym9VH0piCmopmXHJsXGKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoAKS3bf7XNEH91UDrwUB5bouNTZEfr0Vrq2eXsYkskQ1MQRyxKqSHV02TF06wjyrVaDFeIHKlUOGigrFQIHEyaUQLKpzXIoGHJcybl0TN7ocHioZJaw4JQOkEhwskk5DlJBXLrzbT30RejbQtzbfXSIgGm//uQxP+ADnkhK69gYSG2mGX90JlUlemCIWpONhGioo0hKWb+3fC4O0vZrt5OUgBHrUZsnHg1mzy5g7K56CRRhzHmUNtmS+PmlJCM3FaVs/I1anQQTOsiVDADDhxQQPNe5y3OtCYoBhS2uRcbXeXw0WvnjUJdPipv/oTEFNRTMuOTYuMaqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoAAkRFZo291iRM8bwymEkFWvBkmFKJYW3+faUmZjDtnCwrdjqjinW3QdCZG0HnEdJVoVUTNK6ixJElsptySMdLaYvYVa5eslq4Og9bO2QmAvhYdyte3fdk408Jm6SN2OMAFiau5v/f9773W1Py/M/2AE4L//uQxP+CDYDdLa4xAqGuGKV11JhEt9/rGkT+X0SzULnVi07PWXc7/6ap2WChl36kC3G5ifxlHoosRXJtQ3kbU2SIuzVnpN0LpN8U+vTtEdomafoXuZEXv2l3ra+Ztn7X/x5iayvv/n42Xsruqbl0JYhJ1Y/Zfzv6+/x8z+3/W6UxBTUUzLjk2LjGqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoAJFUAVo/3tiROe1wUZu5TgByHACHJ/dnZdGcWCkPBB9phIGbPEGQAMrVBYPQCVXFvwWq49YckeKDAl6ZDNIDEI5qDpKsmqpSBLxBJYxjEHVHbxARUqNBZYHFRE2ePBojXmyGUY1lEs+JQBGRFZ3j/bWNE//uQxP+ADfzlL+4lAmm3pOW1sZj9sawKDnZpnZjT+0x7nuhClJqUdhGF7EKQesCah450tVjke2XAZnYsgRBOpPQ4ZjMaAjGbYolyWEZULsTqZbggVeATbQpPum2mgoGUGTJAdrSwVW7qTR+pKK0xBTUUzLjk2LjGqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoAE0VFZo2+tjROr3EoLbS0CEilOtfLXwe82WBp1zWvNNsuqu5c4QIheMuVl3LNs37zEraFru28mvqoqv3lkbS1DpXsbKDIH7PrDIai08MBRCRzeuKpETYKHaR6F910/hRCpp/+/9X/9f+u2v78wC2Ldv/t//uQxP+ADTD1L+2IY+GJHWY9sIzUq2idZmPG5BfTQy5FOZEjM6banyh31RuppikSnm9fEdVuPLnu2rfaNmCTFECiybTzQ+7cZr1/U6f6Plmro48X7qJnn3G5GnOVnxstozMttJCACImATaAXhgIPCBkdXrs5mSmBjaUxBTUUzLjk2LjGqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoCRFBmdo//+jaMXieIQrKpXc/iDmCNIbFWo4JAgXICauwJSAjSZyOzqCUYYnEjO0IXUFihicwTiSc0EEYYYV506I4DByF036mswr7gkBclQRwz07hiC9DwEMD1zBJH7q/ZzWb/a+zvvf3/YZ+YCjdGv32s//uQxP+ADajvL+0Mw+mqIyX1oJh8iRMvdFhImZFKy9hG1/eMVNoLQUYMQCYkHAxxATDhGMGpNQz1nIIYZwiYkcUgtUQVRAmMaSIq5otM9ITkgswSG4Z3FgAuhHF7KQmGy1ghwEYfTM8+bMEqUvWYnCEJC7r/bv//8t//7RfaYgpqKZlxybFxjVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVUBNEBQV429taIG1CsOTWhLLFnwp/maiqcPJIrqJupWjmezmpFqCf2QNS7M/zKd93JqoQN8Sv9cdRU07L1HcKqfebctmf3/2g7wgRVlEg6GECCJChoutKDM8tJgsU/7Fotb3gRgCKrNH3+0aJlzO5XwP7Zx//uQxP+ADZTxMe0kYGm8HiW1pIwFozDAyzeUAcykkCW/d11WvQgw1Ga7KuSw5fxGtlm92gfnqCD1rNfp8mDIw16LJPW/axBSE2mle1HxBO9187+2MZr3zrR9yofv+239nNbWa5+KhdyE0yVnjExBTUUzLjk2LjFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVUKMWzf/f6xojMrqgKSWT+Ocb5UqwKJNaFOMEIBIiDHcGkRBRMbiBTjgwSPIBARAFCKgR8ILFAQJzrgnDZCQEBoyOL2VxLmUdPKMhFGCjQj2ztdiM+lnWqeGYKn0GA01ooAGJFDZtbxsb2otzFagWmIMN/v//uQxP+ADDztLeyMw+GkqaX9kJh8K0iZAKc2cgjnPH8I18lHVQB8YBcIzCVCQDh5AUBqIwTOjiggdpARE24hrc1K4t2xUWnHDV6IyPNlDkMFNFeZ4Q81InPmYVwjPrJmg5AjRwKkgVHCcSHzIApNEb572WN2JiCmopmXHJsXGKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqoINiTba72IAAETcH7Ov7L7mmGeak5ZilLpGsOOdNtaYZuqn7OGFXVxAotBRsOoVAoTionGhokGrGGlP1K/p0//b//6OtAb4AKJT3//z2JgaeVGEWw6mIKaimZccmxcY1VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV//uQxP+ADakjL6yYYGGXoOW1gIx8VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVU1EWujHeajMjZUAzmTgz7SED185zu4WTl1HDbBXzRxrSVrjMdWTQo2DO8eTLYTDhzs1o6MfXxl5M0WjYw82oTNhNDZF82meNQ1TKewynsMbzzSpY1thNOPjPy0zIeMZGyU4MFWjE080QeEqo1IbNVQjVHc//uQxP+BSIifK6eIYSBCgKUckAAEz2eMSrzCqsyKONHYTUDI00RHpU0ciMqPxGZDAYBAUx0YMkKzIzgyZNMnbDGIswugMTqDHZE0haNVIwFGDTsZoImUlhiRqYYag0wERSIR4wIhMVNjGFcwlsCz2FHkxxkM9OzSAweijQhUz88MqWzD2IwdgBKuYofGRkZkAYAi8IFAgDLqCAACAceHQETGLBpjJEYocmApBCkjp+YQYGLjpkAERJRkQOYyNGDEoqTFUgAI2YYHAovGj0yEKMcJTDTQLHIwamCFRiouY4AER+ZEBmRkBixyYGfGBng4akBUMkZAQFQnKpcOHIFSDD1oQqZixsZGLmOAQOLysWAxUYQEggREAYYKAhgoTD5iwCYuPAQrMCGh4UUGRqMEAQKDBYHEIUIBMRjhCQGDioOMBI2MYATGRQxgxMJRBEigg7BpgYEWmDlRiBmY2kGMM5gr0MQ4WhzIHA0VFNUEgyqNSJTSU4zJvMXeDFXwKt5iykZKYmNDhhI+BCYCl4EMhQuMFIVMQU1FMy45Ni4xVVVV//sQxP+D/jmieA93YwAAADSAAAAEVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVU=").toDestination();

//if loaded then play
Tone.loaded().then(() => {
    player.start();
});
    
</script>
```

Comment: *with an ordinary string (text), say "Hello world", that gets converted into an audio file* - and what would you expect to hear then? Most audio formats (WAV, AIFF, MP3, VOC, and many more) have more or less complex file structures with header parts, data blocks and so on and if that's not correct, it might be difficult to convince a player to play it. Don't know, maybe there's some kind of raw, unstructured format that just interprets every byte in a binary file as a sample value.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm trying to resolve, what parts need to be there (header etc.) and then what parts are the actual sound that can be converted from that text and stuck in between the bits that need to be there. There is an example of something like this here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLK854QyjE4) in Puredata so just try the equivalent is JS world.

Comment: @jps oh and a sort of audiobent sound - similar to that youtube link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Tone.JS. But I have played by raw PCM data with the Web Audio API. The data consists of floating point values that range from -1 to 1. I think a necessary step will be coming up with a transform function that converts your String data to numbers that fall within this range, if you take the path of playing back PCM.

You will need very long strings, though, if your play is a common sample rate of 44100 frames per second, and each char maps to a single frame.

Comment: Tone.js is really irrelevant to this question. I only mentioned it because I used it to resolve the autoplay issue of sound in browsers. That conversion to PCM data is something feasible for me. What does your your PCM player look like? I've spotted one here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921018/web-audio-api-efficiently-play-a-pcm-stream) but it's overly complicated I think. I'm trying to get a sort of audiobent sound (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLK854QyjE4) and am concerned I'll end up with something too controlled.

Comment: Web Audio API can be tricky to learn. Here is an example provided by Mozilla. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer#example Notice that the random values they use to populate the data arrays are values that range between -1 and 1. As long as your conversion algorithm results in values in this range, this code should be able to play it.

Comment: have added what I came up with as an answer but your post and comment here put me on track to this so checked your post as the answer. Not too tricky but I was way off track looking at base64. It has a little of that glitch sound I was hoping for but seems 'soft' and not the typical harsh noise you usually get so I need to work on this - seperate question I think. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, it may be useful to others - convert acsii to decimal, create audiobuffer that's the length of the ascii/decimal, map the decimal between values -1 and 1, put the result into audiobuffer and play it. Not complicated once you know what to look for (which I completely didn't).

```js
// String to convert to audio
var html = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan commodo pretium. Aliquam porta tortor ut quam sagittis posuere. Nullam in condimentum purus, nec vulputate risus. Sed a sollicitudin ipsum. Pellentesque diam nisi, viverra vitae metus at, consectetur posuere lorem. Morbi faucibus sed mi quis cursus. Morbi et tincidunt sem. Phasellus pretium ultricies massa, sit amet consectetur urna rutrum nec. Proin vel velit neque. Fusce eget nulla dui. Phasellus id risus ut lacus laoreet rhoncus. Nunc ultrices eleifend eros, et rhoncus dui dictum sit amet. In dignissim velit ac rhoncus faucibus. Sed viverra lorem at nulla mollis auctor. Etiam vel lacinia neque. Nullam ipsum sapien, rutrum egestas nulla a, efficitur mattis nisi. Nulla non nibh arcu. Vestibulum quis dui non mauris placerat egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla porta id felis sit amet feugiat. Fusce felis metus, ultrices eget posuere id, consectetur nec augue. Nulla nec tortor ac felis rhoncus tempor quis id erat. Nam semper tincidunt ex eu iaculis. Cras a turpis eget dui viverra elementum. In eu orci sodales, ornare leo ut, fermentum elit. Aenean non sem at dui laoreet gravida eu a magna. Praesent vitae urna mattis, efficitur erat id, sagittis neque. Sed sit amet suscipit felis. Nam fringilla ligula leo, vitae malesuada ipsum tincidunt nec. Proin at justo in nisl accumsan consectetur. Phasellus sit amet nisl lacus. Quisque ornare enim laoreet sapien ultricies, ornare faucibus diam condimentum. Donec facilisis at turpis in iaculis. Phasellus laoreet condimentum varius. Phasellus sed dui ut nibh placerat ultrices quis vel lacus. Cras nec vehicula diam. Vivamus vel lacus accumsan, faucibus quam vitae, hendrerit nibh. Aliquam et elementum nunc. Sed mi est, lobortis eu orci sed, tempor vehicula mauris. Aenean non massa varius, ultrices justo eu, cursus ante. In ex nulla, tincidunt eget arcu hendrerit, tempor eleifend ipsum. Vivamus suscipit justo at finibus faucibus. Cras dolor erat, blandit sit amet lacus sit amet, sollicitudin aliquet arcu. Nulla nec sodales neque. Suspendisse sed laoreet mauris. Curabitur sapien neque, lobortis at blandit in, eleifend aliquet velit. Nullam dictum justo quis tellus rutrum, at tincidunt libero iaculis. Nulla convallis eget nisl viverra hendrerit. Nulla imperdiet orci non suscipit elementum. Nunc a metus finibus arcu fermentum porttitor. Morbi semper porttitor cursus.";

// String length
var htmllength = html.length;

// Create an audio context
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// Create an empty three-second stereo buffer at the sample rate of the AudioContext
//const audiobuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, audioCtx.sampleRate * 3, audioCtx.sampleRate);
const audiobuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, htmllength, audioCtx.sampleRate);

// Map a number from one range to another
function map (number, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax)
{
    return (number - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
}

// Fill the buffer with white noise;
// just random values between -1.0 and 1.0
for (var channel = 0; channel < audiobuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++)
{
    // This gives us the actual array that contains the data
    var nowBuffering = audiobuffer.getChannelData(channel);

    // Loop through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < audiobuffer.length; i++)
    {
        // Get each character
        var char = html.charAt(i);

        // Get the character's binary character code (0 - 256)
        var decimal = char.charCodeAt(0);

        // Map binary character code to PCM audio number
        var pcmnumber = map(decimal, 0, 256, -1, 1);

        // Add PCM audio to group of slots in audiobuffer 
        nowBuffering[i] = pcmnumber;
    }
}

// Get an AudioBufferSourceNode.
// This is the AudioNode to use when we want to play an AudioBuffer
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

// set the buffer in the AudioBufferSourceNode
source.buffer = audiobuffer;

// Set volume
gainnode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainnode.gain.value = 1.0;

// Slow down the playback rate
source.playbackRate.value = 0.1;

// connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the
// destination so we can hear the sound
source.connect(gainnode).connect(audioCtx.destination);

// start the source playing
//source.loop = true;
source.start(0);
```